# how to find location of the selected text of pdf in the corresponding xml document using java?

Tags: java, android, xml, pdf

I have pdf and its xml document stored in my database. If I select some text in the pdf then I want to find the location of corresponding xml element in the xml document.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show some efforts to find  a solution yourself

Comment: @AndréSchild I am struggling to find the link between pdf and XML, any suggestions for links or reading material regarding this issue would be welcome.

Comment: Why should the XML have a link to the PDF at all? Is one generated from the other?

Comment: @AndréSchild I have generated a xml file of pdf using pdf to xml converter,now i want to write a code so that if i select a text from the pdf then i can find its location in xml.

Comment: There doesn't exist such a link. The best you could do is do a search inside the XML document too (Including some context infos).